# Plotting smooth line on a scatterplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, scatter-plot

ggplot and smooth line and labelling query for a scatterplot

Hi all

Just a quick ggplot issue.

I have this data table of various cut off points

```
Metric<-c("zero", "D", "H", "W", "P", "C", "J", "L", "N", 
          "M")
F<-c(0, 0.11, 0.26, 0.07, 0.5, 0.07, 0.26, 0.05, 0.29, 0.03)
T<-c(0, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8)
FinalTable<-data.frame(Metric, F, T)
```

and I am trying to draw a smooth line over a scatter gram so it looks similar to this[image]

however when I use my code (see below):
library(ggplot2)

```
ggplot(FinalTable, aes(F, T)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0, 1))+
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=FALSE)
```

It is giving me a less than nice smooth fit: [image]

I also want to add the label next to each data point.

Many thanks in advance for help.

James

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "span=" option in `geom_smooth()` to stiffen the curve.  The default value is 0.75 and using a high value will straight the loess curve.

```
Metric<-c("zero", "D", "H", "W", "P", "C", "J", "L", "N", 
          "M")
F<-c(0, 0.11, 0.26, 0.07, 0.5, 0.07, 0.26, 0.05, 0.29, 0.03)
T<-c(0, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8)
FinalTable<-data.frame(Metric, F, T)

ggplot(FinalTable, aes(F, T)) + 
   geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0, 1))+
   geom_smooth(method="loess", se=FALSE, span=2)
```

[image]

Another option is to use a different function to fit the curve.  The example below is a second order polynomial.

```
ggplot(FinalTable, aes(F, T)) + 
   geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0, 1))+
   geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, formula = "y ~ poly(x, 2)")
```

It will take time to find an appropriate function to fit intercept (0, 0) point and fit the remaining data.